# How to add a changing property to an already existing property in Blazor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm building a language change functionality in a Blazor application. What I have so far is this, this is an example:

```
@page "/example"
@using Blazorserver.Languages
@inject Languages.Dutch dutch
@inject Languages.English english


<p>@dutch.VoorPagina</p> 

<button @onclick="LanguageSwitcher"></button>



@code {
    public static string language = "dutch";
            
    private void LanguageSwitcher()
    {
        if (language == "dutch")
        {
            language = "english";
        }
        else
        {
            language = "dutch";
        }
    }

}
```

What I'm specifically looking for is to have a changing value between the `<p>` tags in the aforementioned example (`<p>@dutch.VoorPagina</p>`). "VoorPagina" is a string from another file that is injected here. I want to be able to change the "dutch" part to "english", so that the same string is changed to a different language. I tried something like `@@dutch.VoorPagina`, so that dutch is a variable that can be changed, but that obviously didn't work. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It is better to use localization services. here is a [sample project](https://github.com/LazZiya/XLocalizer.Samples/tree/master/BlazorLocalizationSample), it is using a custom localization nuget that supports online translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I think it's basically what you're trying to do:

(1) **Add an interface with multiple implementations** in a separate code file.  In real application, I'd have a separate file for each language:

**LanguageInterface.cs**

```
namespace MyLanguages
{
    enum Languages { English, Dutch }
    interface ILanguage
    {
        string Hello { get; }
        string GoodBye { get; }
    }
    class EnglishLanguage : ILanguage
    {
        public string Hello { get; } = "Hello";
        public string GoodBye { get; } = "GoodBye";
    }
    class DutchLanguage : ILanguage
    {
        public string Hello { get; } = "Hallo";
        public string GoodBye { get; } = "Vaarwel";
    }
}
```

(2) Then **instantiate the interface** with whichever class you want to activate:

**Main.razor**

```
@using MyLanguages

<h3>Language Selector</h3>

<button @onclick="@(() => ChangeLanguage(Languages.English))">English</button>
<button @onclick="@(() => ChangeLanguage(Languages.Dutch))">Dutch</button>

@if(CurrentLanguage != null)
{
    <div>@CurrentLanguage.Hello</div>
    <div>@CurrentLanguage.GoodBye</div>
}
@code {
    ILanguage CurrentLanguage { get; set; }

    void ChangeLanguage (Languages languageSelection)
    {
        switch (languageSelection)
        {
            case Languages.English:
                CurrentLanguage = new EnglishLanguage();
                break;
            case Languages.Dutch:
                CurrentLanguage = new DutchLanguage();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

*(DISCLAIMER: it's probably better to look up localization practices for Blazor, and just follow them!)*

Answer (score 1):

I would consider moving the language specific UI texts into a resource file and use standard localization like `IStringLocalizer<Index> localizer`.

Here is a [detailed tutorial](https://soluling.com/Help/Blazor/Index.htm) how to do it.

Or try [this](https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/how-to-localize-texts-in-your-blazor-app-phn). This looks promising, but I did not tried this one out.